# Why does this script not accept any Arabic input?

Tags: javascript, blogger

The code below is a code for the Blogger platform

but the problem with it is that it does not accept any Arabic input

but when converting text via this tool https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ works well please help

```js
var section = {
  category: null,
  "max-results": 6,
  template: {
    default:
      '<div class="card card-masonry col-3-lg col-4-md col-6-sm"><div class="card__content"><div class="card__header"><a class="card__image flex-none" href="URL"><img src="IMG" /></a></div><div class="card__data"><h2 class="card__title card__space"><a href="URL">TITLE</a></h2><div class="card__meta display-flex justify-content-between"><time class="card__space meta__time flx-yc"><svg class="feather feather-clock" fill="none" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg>TIME</time><a class="card__space meta__more flx-yc" href="URL" title="قراءة المزيد"><svg class="feather feather-arrow-left" fill="none" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><line x1="19" x2="5" y1="12" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg></a></div></div></div></div>',
    empty: '<p class="alert">لا توجد مقالات</p>',
  },
};
function forEach(items, callback) {
  var i, item;
  for (i = 0; (item = items[i++]); ) if (false === callback.call(item, i, item)) break;
  return items;
}
function getCurrentData(element) {
  var name, value;
  var obj = {};
  for (name in section) {
    value = element.getAttribute("data-" + name);
    if (value) obj[name] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}
function temp(content, data) {
  var name;
  for (name in data) content = content.replace(new RegExp(name, "g"), data[name]);
  return content;
}
function getLabel(element, data) {
  var name;
  var category = data.category;
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  var src =
    defaults.homeUrl +
    "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=callbacks." +
    category.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/gi, "");
  callbacks[category.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/gi, "")] = function (json) {
    var i, post;
    var html = "";
    var entry = json.feed.entry;
    if (entry)
      for (i = 0; (post = entry[i++]); ) {
        var content = post.content;
        var summary = post.summary;
        var body = content ? content.$t : summary.$t;
        var img = post.media$thumbnail;
        var tempHtml = document.createElement("div");
        tempHtml.innerHTML = body;
        var imgHtml = tempHtml.querySelector("img");
        html += temp(data.template, {
          IMG: (img ? img.url : imgHtml ? imgHtml.src : defaults.image).replace(/s\B\d{2,4}-c/, defaults.imgSize),
          TITLE: post.title.$t,
          TIME: new Date(post.published.$t).toLocaleDateString("ar-EG", { month: "long", day: "2-digit" }),
          SNIPPET: body.replace(/<[^>]*>?/g, "").substring(0, defaults.snippet) + "...",
          URL: function () {
            var i, link;
            for (i = 0; (link = post.link[i++]); ) if (link.rel === "alternate") return link.href;
          },
        });
      }
    else html += section.template.empty;
    element.innerHTML = html;
  };
  for (name in data) if (name !== "template") src += "&" + name + "=" + data[name];
  script.src = src;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
forEach(document.querySelectorAll(defaults.className), function (index, element) {
  var currentData = getCurrentData(element);
  if (currentData.category) {
    if (!currentData["max-results"]) currentData["max-results"] = section["max-results"];
    currentData.template = section.template["default"];
    getLabel(element, currentData);
  }
});
```

When adding the section name in this way it does not work

```
tag: "قسم 5", results: 10
```

But when added this way it works fine

```
tag: "%D9%82%D8%B3%D9%85+5", results: 10
```

I want to add the department name in Arabic without the need to convert it

How can I solve this problem?

Or will one of you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

One of the function of the url encode web you use:

- Convert the character string into a sequence of bytes using the UTF-8 encoding

UTF-8 can store the full Unicode range, so it's fine to use for Arabic. Maybe you dont use utf-8 in your project.

Edit:

Instead of:

```
<p class="alert">لا توجد مقالات</p>
```

try:

```
'<p class="alert"><?php echo 'لا توجد مقالات'; ?></p>'
```

Comment: My experience in JavaScript is not strong, but I want to put the name in Arabic in this script without the need to convert it through the tool that I referred to in the question, but I do not know how to do that

Comment: I edit my answer, check it again. Maybe it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but you did not understand what I mean, this script I got from this add-on in the Blogger platform https://www.zkreations.com/2018/02/secciones-entradas-etiquetas-blogger-json.html and it is specific to the Blogger platform and not Php accepts and also the problem is not in displaying Arabic words, but the problem in using the Arabic language in links